# ASP.NET button works with alerts but not triggering page_load or code behind method

Tags: c#, javascript, webforms, updatepanel, messagebox

I have a ASP.NET button with in a update panel,

if I put alert('hello'), it works otherwise if I put code behind method, it doesn't work, any ideas ?

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="alert('why');" Text="Submit" runat="server" CssClass="leftButton" />       // WORKS !!!


      <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="CodeBEHIND_CLICK" Text="Submit" runat="server" CssClass="leftButton" /> // DOESN'T WORK
```

I tried adding triggers to panel , no change.

**Update**

OnClient or OnCLientClick,  no of them works :(

**UseLess Update**

```
protected void CodeBEHIND_CLICK(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
// its not triggering Page_Load neither this method
}
```

Comment: Your second example has the server side click vent defined in OnClientClick, are you sure you don't want that in OnClick instead?

Comment: show your update button code

Comment: If that will help ! , check my updated question SIR

Comment: not click event ...your button code on aspx page

Comment: Markup is already in my question

Comment: your button is trigger of targetcontrolid to modal popup

Comment: are you using validation controls,,,set CausesValidation="false" on your second button..

Comment: Rahul, this is not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, what was the issue, but I had to create hidden buttons and trigger them for code bind methods triggering.

Answer (score 0):

You need  `OnClick` instead of  `OnClientClick` for binding server side event. You can read more over [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx) about server side click event.

In code behind you should have handler.

```
void CodeBEHIND_CLICK(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Have you defined handler on server side?